# How to skip some characters from formatting in date-fns

Tags: javascript, date-fns

In the folowing example I want to say date-fns do not format `at` (skip these characters):

```
format(DATE, 'cccc, MMMM d at h:mm a')
```

Output is:

```
Thursday, August 8 AM492296400 12:30 AM
```

Expected is:

```
Thursday, August 8 at 12:30 AM
```

Comment: moment js is also a good library to help you out

Comment: @dota2pro we do not use moment js in our new codebases. [more info](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

See the [documentation](https://date-fns.org/docs/format):

> The characters wrapped between two single quotes characters (') are escaped.

```
format(DATE, "cccc, MMMM d 'at' h:mm a")
```

Comment: What if the "part to skip" is dynamic, i.e. "Sat Apr 04 2020...", "Mon Apr 6 2020..." and we'd want to skip the first 4 positions (or even skip first X positions, till whichever position where the month word starts as Mon may be also Monday)

Comment: @zaggi use string template IE `\`'${myEscapedValue}'\``